# initializer list constructor for custom list class

Tags: c++, list, recursion, constructor, initializer

I'm trying to "remake" the list class for a school assignment. However, I haven't got a clue about how to get initializer list constructor to work. What I have so far:

**the ListNodes**

```
struct ListNode
{
   ListNode(int value, ListNode* tail = nullptr) : data(value), next(tail) {}
   int        data;
   ListNode* next;
};
```

**in List.h**

```
List(std::initializer_list<int>);
```

**in List.cc**

```
List::List(std::initializer_list<int> il)
{
  head_ = copy(il, il.size()); //some form of recursive copy-function
}
```

I dont know how to proceed with the copy-function. I've tried std::copy but that just gives me a segfault.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: For each list element, you should call `insert`. Also, you have to write an `insert` function.

Comment: yes, but part of this assignment is that everything that can be handeled recursively should be handeled recursively. Do you have some advice as how to do the insert recursively?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), you can iterate throught an initializer_list with classical begin/end

Comment: Yes, but how do I do it recursively? by calling a `copy(il.begin(), il.end())`? and how should that look? `ListNode* copy(initializer_list<int>::iterator begin, initializer_list<int>::iterator end)`?